# UWP C# How to embed costum font

Tags: c#, fonts, uwp

So i wanted to use a costum font on my uwp app, i download the font from google fonts then added to the folder Fonts the file as been set as content and the file gets copied on the output directory everytime which i guess is the app package?

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Cantami Diva" FontSize="72"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Cantami Diva" FontSize="72" FontFamily="ms-appx:///Assets/Fonts/Arvo-Regular.tff#Arvo"/>
</StackPanel>
```

here is the problem, the second textblock where the font is applied is getting displayed the same as the first, i guess it cant find the font, but if i install the font on my computer it works perfectly, is there no way to use the font without having the user to install it?

[image: My project folder]

Comment: right click font file -> properties and set copy mode to "Do Not Copy" and then try again

Comment: also try adding complete name after the hash like #Arvo-Regular

Comment: Even after i setted to Do Not Copy It doesn't work, i have tried with "#Arvo Regular", "#Arvo-Regular" and "#Arvo", all three of them don't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The True Type Font extension is `.TTF` not `.TFF`

I did a quick test and after changing the typo you had it worked fine for me.

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Cantami Diva" FontSize="24"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Cantami Diva" FontSize="24" FontFamily="ms-appx:///Assets/Fonts/Arvo-Regular.ttf#Arvo"/>
</StackPanel>
```

[image]

Comment: Perphaps im blind but i can't see any typo but for some reason it started working so i guess i will take it.

Comment: From your original post: `"ms-appx:///Assets/Fonts/Arvo-Regular.tff#Arvo"`, note the ".TFF" extension on the font filename.

Comment: I've looked at the same line of code with a typo over and over and don't see my mistake until someone looks over my shoulder and sees it immediately. Everyone does it. 